# how to Stop Axios automatically convert http to https in react js

Tags: reactjs, express, rest, http, axios

how can i solve react using axios to send all the request http to https automatically in between only possible after deployement then it will works fine in localhost but i will faced this issue at deployment i have tried to solve this problem.

i have hosted my client https://mywebsite.com and my server is http://myserver.com.how will i send client https to server http request in axios using react js.

`const privateAPI = axios.create({ baseURL: "http://myserver.com", }); privateAPI.defaults.timeout = 3000;`

change to

`Request URL: https://myserver.com/api/v1/`

how can it will solve I have no idea about it

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, you should use https on both the client and server. So you can set secure sessions and cookies, etc. right?

If you use https on the server side, you can change your DNS settings and add a forwarding route like this:

http://myserver.com >>to forward>> https://myserver.com

Comment: No I didn't forward any Domin it will automatically send a request from http site